# how to merge array of options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in which I have some default set of options and I want to change a few options when I call that function and keep the rest as is, what would be a good approach to do that.

```
updateSlider: function (options) {
    //set default options
    let defaults = {
        slideshow: false,
        slideshowDelay: 2000,
        videos: []
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery's `$.extend` for this purpose

```
updateSlider: function (options) {
    //set default options
    let defaults = {
        slideshow: false,
        slideshowDelay: 2000,
        videos: []
    };
    //merge defaults 
    options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
}
```

Comment: thankyou very much omer that was what i was looking for , it is working great.